# Map One-To-Many to 2 tables at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 2 tables `IncomingCheck` and `OutgoingCheck` which contain many **History** items. To achieve this I've used inheritance and inherited 2 classes for incoming and outgoing histories.

```
public class IncomingCheck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<IncomingCheckHistory> History { get; set; }
    //... other stuff
}

public class OutgoingCheck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OutgoingCheckHistory> History { get; set; }
    //... other stuff
}

public class CheckHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //... other stuff
}

public class IncomingCheckHistory : CheckHistory
{
    public IncomingCheck IncomingCheck { get; set; }
}

public class OutgoingCheckHistory : CheckHistory
{
    public OutgoingCheck OutgoingCheck { get; set; }
}
```

This approach works perfectly. In my database I have a table called `CheckHistories` with 2 nullable columns named `[IncomingCheck_Id]` and `[OutgoingCheck_Id]`.

Now I have created a view on `IncomingCheck` which I created in Sql Server Management Studio and I can get its data using EF:

```
public class ViewIncomingCheck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<IncomingCheckHistory> History { get; set; }
    //... other stuff
}
```

So far so good, but now I want Entity Framework to automatically load the `History` items but when I try to load the data, I get the following error:

`SqlException: Invalid column name 'ViewIncomingCheck_Id'.
Invalid column name 'ViewIncomingCheck_Id'.`

My guess is that the EF is looking for a column named `ViewIncomingCheck_Id` in the `IncomingCheckHistory` table but can't find it.

Is there a way to tell EF that it should use `IncomingCheck_Id` instead of `ViewIncomingCheck_Id`?

Comment: You cannot use `public virtual IList<IncomingCheckHistory> History { get; set; }` in `ViewIncomingCheck` because this mapped to a view and view does not support any relationship like table.

Comment: How can I populate that list then?

Comment: Use `ViewModel` which will contain `ViewIncomingCheck` and `public virtual IList<IncomingCheckHistory> History` and then populate the ViewModel.

Comment: @TanvirArjel unfortunately I can't do it. Due to project restrictions.